# Hiding closed proposals on Area51

Tags: feature-request, area-51

I would like to see a view on Area51 that hides all `[closed]` proposals - right now, they're cluttering-up many pages, and I'd like to be able to see the live proposals without the clutter.

As of 1138EDT on 18-May-2011:

I see 29 on the front page of All looking at "newest" (set to view 50/page).

#### Subtotals:

- Arts: 8
- Business: 2
- Culture: 5
- Life: 13
- Professional: 1
- Recreation: 13
- Science: 2
- Technology : 39

#### Total `[closed]` currently:

- 84

#### Total proposals:

- 508

#### `[Closed]` as a percentage:

- 16.5%

That's some serious clutter, imho :)

Comment: Hey, I'd even be happy if I could search with `closed:0`.

Comment: @Dori - that's saying quite a bit coming from a moderator :)

Comment: @warren Which pages?  The only place I see a lot of them is the "newest" tab, but I'm not sure we want to hide them there.  I'd be fine with adding a search filter for it.

Comment: @David Fullerton, see expansion above

Comment: @Dori actually, you can already search with `closed:0`

Comment: @David - not on newest questions, or with any other filter/sort.

Answer (score 2):

"Proposals" are a lot like "questions" in Stack Exchange (hint — they're derived from the same code base). I think it would become very confusing if we started changing the expected behaviors between the two systems.

Area 51 is supposed to work as much like a Stack Exchange Q&A as possible. **"Hiding" a closed proposal would be much like hiding a closed question.** We've all become accustomed to the behavior that a "closed" question is not deleted. It can be re-opened by voting. Same goes for a closed proposal.

And much like a closed question in Stack Exchange, if you feel that a proposal does not belong on the site, you should vote to deleted it (with the appropriate [reputation requirements](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq), of course). Closed proposals will be deleted automatically if they receive no further activity for a month, anyway.

I would rather *NOT* see the behavior of Area 51 drift too far away from the core functionality of Stack Exchange. Then you would just have *two* sets of behaviors to learn.

Comment: then why not put them all in a view of "closed" like "newest"?

Comment: also - there are only 5 users with the "appropriate reputation requirements" to delete proposals on area51